# Java to AIDL utility

Tags: android, aidl

I have an existing Java interface I'd like to expose via AIDL.
Is there a way to auto generate the AIDL from the Java?

I am aware of Java2IDL for Corba code, so this would be something
similar to that.

Comment: not putting as answer cause I don't know for sure but I think you can just rename the extension to your existing interface to aidl

Answer (score 1):

I think it's hard to do it this way as both Java and AIDL are different languages. Also, it might happen that you are sending and receiving user defined types through AIDL interfaces and that requires additional handling in AIDL. You need to create a separate AIDL file for each parsable type.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge there is no such tool. However, so as aidl differs from java interfaces some decisions should be made by programmers. That's why it's more likely that these tools will not appear.